# Bread and butter pickles without mustard seed?

Tags: canning, pickling, food-processing

I'm making bread and butter pickles and I ran out of mustard seed.  What can I use instead?  Or do I just skip it?

Comment: I've had good horseradish pickles before.  It wouldn't be bread & butter, but it might add a little extra flavor to make up for the loss of the mustard.

Comment: @Joe Interesting idea. That might be really good! OP - Careful though if you try it to not overdo it. Horseradish (in any form) will permeate more and increase in strength over time MUCH more than the same quantity of mustard seed (by volume, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can put whole peppercorns, you can put allspice, you can put cumin seeds. Do one jar with and one without and see what you like.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any really chunky deli mustard just throw a spoonful of that in there.

Comment: Yep. Whole-grain mustard will do nicely in a pinch.